# Spring RestTemplate postForObject with Header: webservice can't find my header parameters

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm struggling with RestTemplate. I need to POST some authentication information to a rest webservice. I can send a request and I get a response. But according to the response my header parameters are not getting through. (Sending the same request with SOAPUI works fine)

This is my code:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
headers.add("companyId", companyId);
headers.add("password", password);              

HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new  ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());           
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

LoginResponse response = (LoginResponse)restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, LoginResponse.class);
```

Anyone who can tell me what's wrong with my HttpEntity or HttpHeader?

thank you.

**SOLVED:**

Ok, finally got it working.

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("companyId", companyId);
map.add("password", password);  

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);      

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());    
messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

LoginResponse response = (LoginResponse) restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, LoginResponse.class);
```

Because I also had a hard time on the response, maybe it can be useful to others:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ItcLoginResponse {

    public String loginToken;

    @JsonProperty("token")
    public String getLoginToken() {
        return loginToken;
    }

    public void setLoginToken(String loginToken) {
        this.loginToken = loginToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: use  'MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' instead of the old 'MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter'

Comment: It looks like the messageConverters instance is Unused in your solution ?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting a header indicating you're posting a form (APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED), but then setting companyId and password as HTTP headers.

I suspect you want those fields to be in the body of your request.

You're also creating an `HttpEntity<String>` which indicates you're going to post a request body containing a String, but you're providing headers but no String.

If that doesn't help you fix it perhaps you can explain what the request is supposed to look like.